# Encrypting data in a Firefox add-on

Tags: perl, encryption, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the request module in the Firefox Add-on SDK to access my Perl application. In the Firefox panel the user will enter his name and password which is relayed to my Perl CGI application.

Firstly, I would like to know if this is a safe approach.

Secondly, is there  any chance of encrypting the data and then decrypting it again on the server side (written in Perl using the CGI module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, I would like to know if this is a safe approach.

As far as the client-side goes - depends on how you store this password. If you remember the password rather than requiring the user to enter it again each time then you should [use Login Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/Using_nsILoginManager) for that (which stores it encrypted if the user defined a master password). When using Add-on SDK you will need [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) for that:

```js
var {Cc, Ci, components} = require("chrome");
```

You can then replace `Components.classes` in the examples by `Cc`, `Components.interfaces` by `Ci` and `Components.Constructor` by `components.Constructor` and these code snippets should work correctly in your extension.

> Secondly, is there any chance of encrypting the data and then decrypting it again on the server side

If your goal is to protect against eavesdropping then you do *not* want to use symmetrical encryption - it uses the same key for encryption and decryption and the key used for encryption will be visible to anybody looking at the source code of your extension. So you want to use an asymmetric (public-key) encryption algorithm like RSA. However, using it "manually" in Firefox is currently very complicated and involves accessing the [NSS library](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/) via [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes) ([DOMCrypt extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/domcrypt/) does it this way). Not to mention that you would still have to think about [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) and such. The much simpler solution would be using an HTTPS connection to communicate with the server.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will get onto it.